# How to change author and email on specified commit without changing the last commit

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a specified commit on the last 8 commit but I cant find it when I type 
`git rebase -i -p 26caa0ff`

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

I change `pick` to `edit` on my specified hash. and my global user & email already changed

I already done and success, but on my gitlab.com, it didn't change.
[image]

Comment: What is the commit you want to change? Is it the one with SHA 26caa0ff?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you specify a single commit like that, it's treated as the "upstream", meaning it won't be modified - only commits after the upstream point will be rebased.

`git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>]
               [<upstream> [<branch>]]`

What you want is to set the upstream to the commit before that. Try this instead:

`git rebase -i -p 26caa0ff~`

In response to your updated question:

> I change pick to edit on my specified hash. and my global user & email
>   already changed I already done and success, but on my gitlab.com, it
>   didn't change.

You absolutely should not be modifying history (rebase) on a public branch or something that is being shared.  But if you absolutely must, you would need to force push this change: `git push -f origin ...`

Comment: Note: "How to change author and email on specified commit without changing the last commit" -> If you want to change the author, it WILL change the commit hash, as the hash is based on metadata like author.

Comment: @jeraldpunx i updated my answer, though if you have a totally different question, you should just post a new questiton instead of editing something that people have already started answering

Comment: if I used that? does the latest commit will not be removed and not changed too? and my commit will stays the same date or position. I only intend to edit author name into mine only.

Comment: if you do git fetch and git log origin <branch> and can see the updated author but in gitlab the out-of-date author is still shown, then it probably means something is not working with the gitlab interface.

Comment: its still the outdated author

Comment: then it sounds like you didn't actually update the author locally or you didn't actually push it or to the right branch

Comment: ahh its all done now, i just need to `git push -f` on it. I don't know why these tutorials incomplete.

Comment: yeah I mentioned that, please mark that question as answered :)